# Relative URI string does not validate against format 'uri'

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonschema

I have a simple class that looks like this.

```
public class Entity
{
    [Required] [JsonProperty("_links")]
    public Dictionary<string, Link> Links { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    [JsonProperty("href")] [Required] [MinLength(14)] [MaxLength(255)]
    public Uri Href { get; set; }
}
```

When I generate a schema for these 2 classes as shown the `Href` property is getting a `"format": "uri"` attribute added to it:

```
{
  "$id": "Entity",
  "definitions": {
    "Link": {
      "$id": "Link",
      "type": [
        "object",
        "null"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "href": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 14,
          "maxLength": 255,
          "format": "uri"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "href"
      ]
    }
```

My links are all relative links in this data store.  When I try to validate something like this snippet of JSON, I get `String '/api/sys/map/foo01' does not validate against format 'uri'.`
Is there some way to decorate my Href property to get JSon.Net Schema to use `format : uri-relative` instead?

E.g. given the following JSON:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "foo": {
      "href": "/api/sys/map/foo01"
    }
  }
}
```

If I manually change the schema from `"uri"` to `"uri-relative"` it parses fine.  Wondering how I can get this into the generated schema.  I am using JSon.Net Schema 3.0.11.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the `"format"` to use for a relative URI is **`"uri-reference"`** not `"uri-relative"`, according to *[JSON Schema Validation: A Vocabulary for Structural Validation of JSON: draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-02](https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.7.3.5)*.

That being said, there doesn't seem to be a way currently to make Json.NET Schema generate a `"uri-reference"` format for a `Uri` property using only attributes.  If I search the [3.0.11 source tree](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/tree/3.0.11) or [latest (3.0.12) source tree](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/tree/master) for [`Formats.UriReference`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/blob/3.0.11/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/Infrastructure/Constants.cs#L96), I get [two results](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/search?q=Formats.UriReference&unscoped_q=Formats.UriReference), none of which are involved with schema generation.

Thus it will be necessary to use a [custom `JSchemaGenerationProvider`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/CreateCustomProvider.htm) to generate the necessary schema for `Link`.  However, schema generation is involved and [`JSchema`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_JSchema.htm) itself is quite complex, so what we would like to do is to generate a default schema for it, then tweak the schema's properties as needed.

To accomplish this, first create an abstract [`JSchemaGenerationProvider`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_Generation_JSchemaGenerationProvider.htm) called `SchemaCustomizationGenerationProvider`.  It generates schemas for selected types by temporarily disabling itself in a thread-safe manner then recursively calling `context.Generator.Generate` to generate a default schema.  That default schema can then be customized before being returned:

```
public abstract class SchemaCustomizationGenerationProvider : JSchemaGenerationProvider
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    static HashSet<Tuple<Type, Type>> _types;

    HashSet<Tuple<Type, Type>> TypesBeingGenerated { get { return _types ?? (_types = new HashSet<Tuple<Type, Type>>()); } }

    void PushType(Type type)
    {
        if (!TypesBeingGenerated.Add(Tuple.Create(GetType(), type)))
        {
            throw new JSchemaException(string.Format("Unexpected recursion for type {0}", type));
        }
    }

    void PopType(Type type) { TypesBeingGenerated.Remove(Tuple.Create(GetType(), type)); }

    bool CurrentlyGeneratingForType(Type type) { return TypesBeingGenerated.Contains(Tuple.Create(GetType(), type)); }

    static JsonContract GetContract(JSchemaTypeGenerationContext context) { return context.Generator.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(context.ObjectType); }

    static Type GetType(JsonContract contract) { return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(contract.UnderlyingType) ?? contract.UnderlyingType; }

    public sealed override bool CanGenerateSchema(JSchemaTypeGenerationContext context)
    {
        var contract = GetContract(context);
        var type = GetType(contract);
        if (CurrentlyGeneratingForType(type))
            return false;
        if (!CanCustomize(context, contract, type))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public override JSchema GetSchema(JSchemaTypeGenerationContext context)
    {
        var contract = GetContract(context);
        var type = GetType(contract);
        PushType(type);
        try
        {
            return Customize(context, contract, type, context.Generator.Generate(context.ObjectType));
        }
        finally
        {
            PopType(type);
        }
    }

    protected virtual bool CanCustomize(JSchemaTypeGenerationContext context, JsonContract contract, Type type)
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected abstract JSchema Customize(JSchemaTypeGenerationContext context, JsonContract contract, Type type, JSchema schema);
}
```

Next create `UriReferenceAttribute` to mark `Uri` properties that should be interpreted as relative Uri's, and `UriReferenceGenerationProvider` to correct the schemas for properties so marked:

```
[System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class UriReferenceAttribute : System.Attribute
{
}

public sealed class UriReferenceGenerationProvider : SchemaCustomizationGenerationProvider
{
    public const string UriReference = "uri-reference";
    public const string Uri = "uri";

    protected override bool CanCustomize(JSchemaTypeGenerationContext context, JsonContract contract, Type type) { return contract is JsonObjectContract; }

    protected override JSchema Customize(JSchemaTypeGenerationContext context, JsonContract contract, Type type, JSchema schema)
    {
        foreach (var property in ((JsonObjectContract)contract).Properties.Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(Uri) && p.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(typeof(UriReferenceAttribute), true).Any()))
        {
            JSchema propertySchema;
            if (!schema.Properties.TryGetValue(property.PropertyName, out propertySchema))
                continue;
            propertySchema.Format = UriReference;
        }
        return schema;
    }
}
```

This all being done, modify `Link` as follows:

```
public class Link
{
    [JsonProperty("href")] [Required] [MinLength(14)] [MaxLength(255)]
    [UriReferenceAttribute] // Add this
    public Uri Href { get; set; }
}
```

And you can get your required schema using the following code:

```
var generator = new JSchemaGenerator() 
{ 
    GenerationProviders = { new UriReferenceGenerationProvider() },
    // Your pre-existing settings (not shown in your question) here
    SchemaIdGenerationHandling = SchemaIdGenerationHandling.TypeName,
};
var generatedSchema = generator.Generate(typeof(Entity));
```

Notes:

- I believe the reason that `"format": "uri-relative"` worked for you is that Json.NET Schema apparently ignores unrecognized formats during validation.  `"format": "something-completely-unknown"` also validates your JSON successfully.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MBrC4s).

Comment: Thanks for the input.  typed from memory after a long night.  Feel free to edit the original so it's more useful to future searchers.